# Why am I failing DNS lookup when connecting to MongoDB from IntelliJ?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, amazon-web-services, dns

I am connecting to a MongoDB instance from a Java project running via Maven in IntelliJ. However, the DNS lookup for the DB fails. The exact inner exception is as follows:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: DNS error [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]; remaining name '<DBADDRESS>.mongodb.net'
    at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:316)
    at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81)
    at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:434)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:141)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:129)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:171)
    at com.mongodb.internal.dns.JndiDnsClient.getResourceRecordData(JndiDnsClient.java:41)
    ... 116 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.trustedBlockingReceive(DatagramChannelImpl.java:703)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.blockingReceive(DatagramChannelImpl.java:633)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.receive(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:240)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:700)
    at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(DnsClient.java:425)
    at jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:214)
```

I am able to connect to this DB from Mongo Compass just fine, and other people on my team are able to connect with this Java program on machines with identical architecture. They are on the same VPN and WiFi as me, and I have verified the DNS lookup is going to the exact same nameserver.

Other things I have tried:

- recloning the entire repo
- clearing any DNS caches
- changing nameserver
- updating drivers and maven packages

Does anyone have any suggestions? Or is there any additional info I can provide that may help?

Comment: Please show your properties that are defining the mongo host or url.

Comment: @Lloyd Ollerhead is this issue resolved?  I am facing the same issue, able to open using Robo3t but not able to connect from code.